# Using Gson and Anko

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I have a JSON and I want to use the data from it in my app but I am not able to parse the JSON correctly so I can use the values from the JSON to set different buttons texts in the fragment.
The problem is that I get null every time I in `feed.first_film`.
I am using Gson.

> My JSON

```
{
"data": {
    "films": [
        {
            "film_id": "8",
            "first_film": "Dunkirk",
            "first_thumb": "firstlog.jpg",
            "first_desc": "Action- Drama-History",
            "second_film": "The Good Doctor S1 E11",
            "second_thumb": "secondlog.png",
            "second_desc": "Drama",
            "third_film": "Pirates Of The Caribbean Dead Men Tell No Tales",
            "third_thumb": "thirdlog.png",
            "third_desc": "Action- Fantasy-Adventure",
        }
    ]
}
}
```

> My Main Activity.kt

```
class MoviesFrag : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {
    var moviesURL: String? = null
    var ds: String? = null
    val url = "http://sign.aya.sy/mobi/index.php/welcome/get_films_det"
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        doAsync() {
            firstEx()
            uiThread {
                activity!!.longToast(ds)
            }
        }
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movies_frag, container, false)
        return view
    }
    fun firstEx() : Films{
        val moviesJsonString = URL(url).readText()
        Log.i("Json", moviesJsonString)
        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
        val feed = gson.fromJson(moviesJsonString, Films::class.java)
        ds = feed.first_film
        return feed
    }
```

> My DataClass.kt

```
data class MoviesData(val data: Data)

data class Data(val films: List<Films>)
data class Films(val film_id: String,
                 val first_film: String,
                 val first_thumb: String,
                 val first_desc: String,
                 val second_film: String,
                 val second_thumb: String,
                 val second_desc: String,
                 val third_film: String,
                 val third_thumb: String,
                 val third_desc: String,
                 val desc: String)
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? What do you mean by "not able to parse correctly"?

Comment: What you want in parsing?

Comment: The 'feed.first_film' gives null

Comment: Can you pest your Films Model class

Comment: @BhavyaGandhi Done

Comment: I will post my answer .Check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Model Name `MoviesData` Form `Films`,

```
 val moviesData= gson.fromJson(moviesJsonString, MoviesData::class.java)//Here you get moviesData array .
```